# how do you pass booleans from PHP controller to Ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, boolean

I used this system.. sendind a json with success = 0 or 1 depending on success or error, is this correct or there is a better more correct method to pass true or false to the ajax call?

```
 if (empty($item)) {

                // add to the DB

                $return['success'] = 0;
                return Response()->json($return);

            } else {

                $return['success'] = 0;
                $return['message'] = "Already in Collection";
                return Response()->json($return);

            }
```

then in Ajax:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $("body").on("submit", ".dynamic-form", function (e) {    
            var form = $(this);
            var span = $(form).find('input[name="span_id"]').val();    
            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success == 1) {

                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else if (data.success == 0) {

                        alert("error");    
                    }   
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `true` or `false` and then compare like that `if (data.success)`.
If you want a boolean send a boolean, but it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This depends only on you, you can save your `success` as you do or to `status`...

```
<?php
if (empty($item)) {
    // add to the DB

    $return['success'] = true;
} else {

    $return['success'] = false;
    $return['message'] = "Already in Collection";
}

return Response()->json($return);
```

Comment: Well I was doing like that but then ajax considered everything true.

Comment: @Chriz74 And which alert do you have success or error. And is your data parsed as json?